# Azure Pipeline Approval Notifications - What happens if the email service is down?

Tags: azure-devops, notifications, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We've began the mass rollout of Azure DevOps across our business and one of the capabilities that has attracted the most interest is Azure Pipelines. The question has however been asked by one of our Release Management stakeholders that should our email service be down (whether at the individual user or organisational level), how do we proceed with the release approval process?

Essentially, the question therefore being asked is what other Approval notification options are available to us aside email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this time, however, Azure DevOps only send notifications though email.

So if you want to recieve approval notifications, you need to enable the "Deployment approval pending" notification, otherwise you need to go to Azure DevOps periodically to see if there are any release stages that need to be approved.